# How to index the attributes of the associated table in Oracle？

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, datagrip

In order to optimize the query of the following statement add an index:

```
SELECT SUPPLIER.COMPANY_NAME, SUPPLIER.CITY
FROM PRODUCT JOIN SUPPLIER
ON PRODUCT.SUPPLIER_NAME = SUPPLIER.COMPANY_NAME;
```

The statement I wrote is as follows：

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT PRODUCT.SUPPLIER_NAME, SUPPLIER.COMPANY_NAME FROM PRODUCT,SUPPLIER;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
CREATE INDEX PS_IDX_SC ON PRODUCT,SUPPLIER(PRODUCT.) ;
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT PRODUCT.SUPPLIER_NAME, SUPPLIER.COMPANY_NAME FROM PRODUCT JOIN SUPPLIER;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
DROP INDEX PS_IDX_SC;
```

How to write the statement on line 45,thanks.

[image: reference]

Answer (score 1):

You can not crete the index on two tables.

You need to create two separate index as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX PS_IDX_PS ON PRODUCT(SUPPLIER_NAME) ; 

CREATE INDEX PS_IDX_SC ON SUPPLIER(COMPANY_NAME) ;
```

Comment: Thank you I'm learning Oracle and theres many questions i meet.

Comment: Try it and if it works for it then you should accept the answer so that your question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer your question in a different way, trying to give you a short overview of what indexes are for, and that sometimes they are not the answer. You are joining two tables based on a condition, but without filtering. When you need to analyse a performance issue, and you think an index is the answer, try to think a bit more.

In your specific case, the join has no filter, so you show the supplier name and company name. But your query shows two columns only: supplier_name from the product table, and company_name from the supplier table. However, what is the join condition here ? I guess that company_name and supplier_name are the same, however it does not make any sense to retrieve the same column from both tables, if you ask me.

**Original query**

```
SQL> SELECT PRODUCT.SUPPLIER_NAME, SUPPLIER.COMPANY_NAME FROM PRODUCT JOIN SUPPLIER;
```

**Rewrite query**

```
SQL> SELECT PRODUCT.SUPPLIER_NAME, SUPPLIER.COMPANY_NAME FROM PRODUCT JOIN SUPPLIER 
     on PRODUCT.SUPPLIER_NAME = SUPPLIER.COMPANY_NAME;
```

Try to write always the join condition, makes the query more readable. In your case you could create two indexes in both tables, as @Tejash has shown you before, but let me explain you a bit more something else.

- If your SQL query only retrieves the columns present in the index, Oracle probably will use the indexes to access the data. In this case, accessing by index will be faster than by table because the indexes are smaller than the tables.
- However, if your SQL query retrieves more columns than the ones contained in the indexes (for example, the product_name), then it would be very interesting see whether than indexes make the query faster when you have no filter on it. In this case Oracle probably would use a method called TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID. It means that Oracle access the index to retrieve the rowid, then it goes to the table to get the data using the rowid retrieved from the index. In this case, when more columns are involved, if the tables are big enough, I bet accessing by table full scan is faster than accessing by index.

**My advice:** Get statistics of both tables by using DBMS_STATS. And, if you have Oracle 11g or higher, that you most probably do, you might want to use **Invisible Indexes** to verify the performance of those queries when you add the indexes without affecting your environment, then when you are sure, you can make them visible.

```
SQL> CREATE INDEX IDX_PRO_SUP ON PRODUCT(SUPPLIER_NAME) INVISIBLE;

SQL> CREATE INDEX IDX_SUP_COM SUPPLIER(COMPANY_NAME) INVISIBLE;
```

To see how the indexes will work with your explain plan in your own session.

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET OPTIMIZER_USE_INVISIBLE_INDEXES=TRUE;
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT PRODUCT.SUPPLIER_NAME, SUPPLIER.COMPANY_NAME FROM 
     PRODUCT,SUPPLIER;
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
```

Then when you are sure those indexes work as you expect:

```
SQL> ALTER INDEX IDX_PRO_SUP VISIBLE;

SQL> ALTER INDEX IDX_SUP_COM VISIBLE;
```

Hope it helps.
Best regards

Comment: Thank you and I need to spend some time to understand your answer better and then I will ask you more questions.